# How to change css property using jquery with this code

Tags: jquery, css

"#business" is currently set to background: #323232;  How can I change it to #000; after I click on "#business" and back to 323232 once the menu is closed?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#business").click(function(){
        jQuery.fx.off = true;
        $("#businessmenu").toggle("");
    });

    $('html').click(function() {
        $("#businessmenu").hide("");
    });

    $('#business').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

Here is the html:

```
<a href="#" id="business">Biz name</a>
<div id="businessmenu">
    <a href="help.html">Help</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to change a CSS property (or multiple properties if necessary):

```
$("#business").click(function(event){
    jQuery.fx.off = true;
    $("#businessmenu").toggle("");
    $(this).css("background-color", "#000");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$('html').click(function() {
    $("#businessmenu").hide();
    $("#business").css("background-color", "#323232");
});
```

Note that I've combined the 2 event listeners you had bound to `#business` as it's makes no difference to just bind the one.

As a side note, is there a reason you are passing an empty string to `hide`? That shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the background of an element (in your case "#business") to a color, you simply do:

```
$("#business").css({
     "background": "#000"
});
```

But I am not sure what you mean by the "menu", you should probably show us the code of your HTML!

Comment: I put the html above.. Essentially you click on the #business and it shows "#businessmenu"

Answer (score 1):

The `css` function is used for changing CSS properties like background.

```
$('html').click(function() {
  $('#businessmenu').hide("");
  $('#busniessmenu').css('background-color', '#323232');
});

$('#business').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).css('background-color', '#000');
});
```