# Pie chart legend not showing - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, legend, pie-chart

I have to show legends for a pie chart. I have been following below link.

> http://jsfiddle.net/vrwjfg9z/

But it does not work for me in  below code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>ChartJS - Pie Chart</title>


      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Chart.js"></script>

        <script src="veeva-library.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="veevaMessages.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="MyInsightsLibrary.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
    <span style="float: left;margin-left:2em"> <b>Date Range: </b>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" > <b>to </b>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker2"> </span><div id = "Alert" style="float:left;margin-left:2em"> Please select a valid Date Range!</div>
       <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"> 
        <canvas id="mycanvas" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"></canvas>  <!--width="300" height="300">-->
       </div>
        <div id="js-legend" style="display: inline-block;width: 12px; height: 12px; margin-right: 5px;"></div>    <!-- class="chart-legend"  -->
      </body>  
        <script>


var startDate;
    var endDate;
    var start;
    var end;

        $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                onSelect: function() {
                    startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    start = formatDate(startDate);
                    if( start!=null && end!=null && end>=start)
                    {document.getElementById('Alert').style.visibility = 'hidden';

                    init();

                    }
                    else {
                    document.getElementById('Alert').style.visibility = 'visible'; //Will show
                    }
                }

            });
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
                onSelect: function() {
                    endDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    end = formatDate(endDate);
                    alert('skn here s' + startDate);
                    alert('skn here e' + endDate);
                    if( start!=null && end!=null && end>=start)
                    {document.getElementById('Alert').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                    init();
                    }



        else {
                        document.getElementById('Alert').style.visibility = 'visible'; //Will show
                              }
                    }

                });

            });




                function init(){


                            var dynamicColors = function() {
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
    }
                    var data = [
                        {
                            value: 270,
                            color: dynamicColors(),  //"cornflowerblue",
                            highlight: dynamicColors(), //"lightskyblue",
                            label: "Corn Flower Blue"
                        },
                        {
                            value: 50,
                            color: dynamicColors(), //"lightgreen",
                            highlight: dynamicColors(), //"yellowgreen",
                            label: "Lightgreen"
                        },
                        {
                            value: 40,
                            color: dynamicColors(), //"orange",
                            highlight: dynamicColors(),//"darkorange",
                            label: "Orange"
                        }
                    ];




    var options = {
        segmentShowStroke: false,
        animateRotate: true,
        animateScale: false,
        percentageInnerCutout: 50,
        tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>n"
    };
                    var ctx = document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d");
                    //draw
                    var mycanvas = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data,options);
                    document.getElementById('js-legend').innerHTML = mycanvas.generateLegend();

                    }



            </script>

    </html>
```

I am getting below error in console. I do understand from google search that it needs somewhere to put document.ready or some onload function which I am not sure of.
**Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at init & at onload
```

Can someone please let me know where I go wrong?

Please find the screenshot how the legend shows for me without rectangular color boxes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaMEr.jpg)

Comment: `</div` that's not how a div starts

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not finding your div `#js_legend` because you did not write it properly in your HTML. It should be this:

```
<div id="js-legend" style="display: inline-block;width: 12px; height: 12px; margin-right: 5px;"></div>
```

Instead of this:

```
</div id="js-legend" style="display: inline-block;width: 12px; height: 12px; margin-right: 5px;"></div>
```

Something else I noticed is, why are you using the traditional JavaScript `document.getElementsById()` when you're using jQuery? You ought to use the **$** operator, like you're supposed to. I noticed this line that you have.

```
document.getElementById('js-legend').innerHTML = mycanvas.generateLegend();
```

This is bad practice in jQuery, and it screws up the flow of your script, it might even make things malfunction.

```
$("#js-legend").html(mycanvas.generateLegend());
```

To change the visibility property of your elements, you will want to use the jQuery [**`.css()`**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function. Also, [have a look at this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285533/how-to-change-css-property-using-jquery-with-this-code) You should use the following syntax, as opposed to invoking `.style.visibility` the way you would in traditional JavaScript.

```
$("#Alert").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

Comment: Thanks I have modified it but please find the way legends are expected in that fiddle link is not happening for me.